# How can I create a Jenkins pipeline to run a Java Application on a schedule?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to create a Jenkins pipeline on an existing Jenkins environment that would run an application (hosted on an online SCM repository) on a schedule. The application to run would be a Java .jar  file. Is my understanding correct that this would entail a Jenkins Job that would build an application on a server, then through a script (perhaps .sh?) of some sort run that application. Upon completion the build would be cleaned up and removed from the server. Is this correct? Am I missing any parts or steps in my understanding? How can I structure such a jenkins job?

Comment: Did you read [Jenkins User Handbook: Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) ?